# "IN" NSPredicate where the search is made within an array of objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit, nspredicate

I have an array called `deletedDepartments` which contains NSObjects called DeletedObject. A DeletedObject only has a field called `deletedID`. This array is generated from a mapping with RestKit.

Now, I want to search within CoreDate for `Department` objects where their `id` is within the `deletedDepartments` array.

If I do

```
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id IN %@", deletedDepartments ]];
```

This won't work because deletedDepartments is not a NSArray made of NSNumber, but of NSObject which contains the NSNumber I want to compare. How can I achieve such thing **without** creating another array made from iterating over the `deletedDepartments` and selecting only the `deletedID`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your predicate to the following :

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"deletedID IN %@", [deletedDepartments valueForKey:@"deletedID"]]
```

This will create an array of your deletedId's, and evaluate each object using the deletedId property. While, yes, this does internally iterate over the array to create a new one, that's the best you can do unless the NSObjects in `deletedDepartments` are of the same class as the model objects that your are fetching.